# Jenkins - How to use the same workspace as Multi-branch for Jenkins PR jobs

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

**Backgroud:**

I have setup a Multi-branch job that checks the repository and triggers through the Github webhook a build for every push on a branch.

Jenkinsfile is present on branches.

There are several stages present but the `checkout scm` is made using the same workspace location for all branches (repo > 1GB):

```
node("Node_Name") {
    ws(workspacePath) {
        echo "Checking out code on ${env.NODE_NAME}"
        checkout scm

        buildSolution()
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When I set up to also trigger a job at a pull request, that particular job is triggered but it's ignoring the custom workspace set up in `Jenkinsfile` (present in both branches).

Any hints on how I could solve this? Checking out the entire repository (> 1GB) for every pull request takes up a lot of time, so I'd prefer avoiding this.

Comment: Do your branches happen to have slashes in them? Ex: `release/1.0.0` . This could be an issue as I've run into it before. Also you could look into doing a shallow clone and/or shallow fetch of the repo so you don't have to copy the entire git history by putting `[$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 1, noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 5],` into the `scm[]` portion of your jenkinsfile.

Comment: I had branches with slashes, but when I gave a try to some branches without I got the same result. 
I know that I can do a shallow clone, but still, it doesn't make sense for all the branch jobs triggered by the github-webhook to follow the custom workspace and the PR ones not...

Comment: @Cosmin Having the same issue, did you end up ever finding a workaround?